# How to make a received GitHub PR with changed history ff-mergeable?

Tags: git, github, pull-request, git-rewrite-history

A user created a PR with a single commit in my repository on GitHub.

Since the PR, changes were pushed to the main repository, so the merge could not be fast-forward.

TL;DR

I pulled his branch, rebased a couple of times and pushed to origin, so the PR commit now has a different hash, and the GitHub PR was not automatically marked as pulled in.

---

I was working on a topic branch and fetched his master.

```
* 5977cb4 - (user/master) PR <user>
| * 857775e - (HEAD -> topic) topic commeit. <me>
| | * 871201e - (master) Local changes in master <me>
| |/  
| * f648f4e - (origin/master) Changes in origin <me>
|/  
* 3461bd2 - Initial commit <me>
```

and then rebased upon his master branch

```
➜  local git:(topic) git rebase user/master
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: Changes in origin
Applying: topic commeit.

* 1e2fe2e - (HEAD -> topic) topic commeit. <me>
* 1c7caa9 - Changes in origin <me>
* 5977cb4 - (user/master) PR <user>
| * 871201e - (master) Local changes in master <me>
| * f648f4e - (origin/master) Changes in origin <me>
|/  
* 3461bd2 - Initial commit <me>
```

and then rebased it on my master and ff-merged topic in order to push to origin:

```
➜  local git:(topic) git rebase master
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: PR
Applying: topic commeit.

➜  local git:(topic) git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
➜  local git:(master) git merge topic
Updating 871201e..836e09d
Fast-forward
```

And pushed it to origin:

```
* 836e09d - (HEAD -> master, origin/master, topic) topic commeit. <me>
* 46e591a - PR <user>
* 871201e - Local changes in master <me>
* f648f4e - Changes in origin <me>
| * 5977cb4 - (user/master) PR <user>
|/  
* 3461bd2 - Initial commit <me>
```

by now, the PR commit has a different hash and the GitHub PR did not pick it up.

Now, I cannot cleanly pull it in, as I already have the commit changes in history, only with a different hash.

**I would prefer to have GitHub mark it as merged, so it does not appear as though I rejected the changes.**

What should I instruct the user to do such that the PR will be fast-forward merge-able? Should he simply pull my master branch? What can I do in the future to handle such cases more cleanly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Github's Pull Requests are never merged in a fast-forward way. That's by design, so it's clearly stated **who approved** the inclusion of those commits authored by a stranger.

From GitHub's Help [Merging a pull request](https://help.github.com/articles/merging-a-pull-request/):

> Pull requests are merged using the `--no-ff` option.

So you can merge the PR in a no-ff way, or cherry-pick the commit and close the PR. In both cases, the authorship will be intact, and a *Thank you* message in the PR is worth more than a `Merged` status for the contributor's point of view.

If you decide to merge the PR, you can ask the contributor to rebase her branch on top of the current `master` so the history doesn't diverge that much, but it may not be worth to introduce that bureaucracy to the workflow.

Keeping a clean history is great, but there are cases in which a clean history isn't a linear one - don't try to over-engineer it :)

Comment: I ended up manually merging the commits using the method described by GitHub (pull remote into a new branch, merge from master, push). This means 2 commits with the same content (but different hashes) exist in 2 different branches, which have been merged without affecting the final version of the code. Thanks for the tips!